# How to add an Image in the title bar?

Tags: c#, wpf

The icon in the title bar is too small, so I want to add Image instead of Icon.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't like to use the icon, the single way to do this is to make a custom title bar, I think...

You can use this code:
This is the XAML code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowStyle="None">
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF00860C" BorderThickness="3" Name="border1" Margin="0,30,0,0"></Border>
    <Rectangle Name="rectangle1" Stroke="#FF2446FF" StrokeThickness="3" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseDown="rectangle1_MouseDown">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.013" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF7CAEFF" Offset="0.477" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Button Content="X" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,3,3,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Button Content="□" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,3,26,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Click="button2_Click" />
    <Button Content="__" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,3,49,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Click="button3_Click" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,4,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="Custom Title bar" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" MouseDown="rectangle1_MouseDown"/>
    <Image Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,4,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="26" />
</Grid>
```

And this is the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)

                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            else
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void rectangle1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DragMove();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Working for one. Just wait. :D

Comment: There should ways to customize title bars using the [shell integration library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell/).

Comment: Could you tell me how to move that form?

Comment: Oh... That's my problem too. I am searching now.

Comment: could you tell me how to click on maximize button to restore size?