# how to customize titlebar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add an Image in the title bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642552/how-to-add-an-image-in-the-title-bar)

I want to customize Titlebar in WPF (C#).
Could you tell me how to add 3 Images instead maximize button (normal, over, press)?

Answer (score -1):

Please use **Bland** for that. Change the images of that button and also change its event code.