# How to add any image as a icon in title?

Tags: html, favicon

I want to add an image as a favicon in title. The image is 300px and is located in images folder. I want to display the image besides the title.

I tried to do it but it does not display it:

```
<head>
<title>My title</title>
<link rel="shortcut" href="./images/logo">
</head>
```

It does not display any logo besides my title how can I add the logo with my title.

Comment: You have defined your icon path without the extension, its probably `logo.png`? Also take a look [at requirements for a favicon](https://sympli.io/blog/2017/02/15/heres-everything-you-need-to-know-about-favicons-in-2017/).

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Should the size of image be small as it's size is 300px in images folder

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Also can I add any images as favicon ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an Image in the title bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642552/how-to-add-an-image-in-the-title-bar)

Comment: @VirendersinghRathore this is a question about a desktop app.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova My question is not duplicate I have checked out that question but it doesn't seem to be similar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a favicon to a static HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943771/adding-a-favicon-to-a-static-html-page)

Comment: @IvankaTodorova I have added favicon in images folder and index.html is in docs folder and my docs and images folder are in my main folder what `href=""` should I use for my favicon ? `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/logo.png">` but does not work can you tell me how to fix the path ?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova Can you please clarify my above doubt?

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48822168/how-to-add-any-image-as-a-icon-in-title/48822338#48822338) @stonerock to see how to fix your problem.

Comment: @AngelPolitis Great answer thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to set a favicon to your page you have to note the following:

- your image is of the correct dimensions *(`300px` is too big to be used as a favicon)*.
- to achieve cross-browser support, you'll need different sizes and different `link` tags.

Usually, one `180x180`, one `32x32` and one `16x16` will suffice to cover all browsers and devices.

**Code:**

```
<link rel = "apple-touch-icon" sizes = "180x180" href = "images/logo180x180.png">
<link rel = "icon" type = "image/png" sizes = "32x32" href = "images/logo32x32.png">
<link rel = "icon" type = "image/png" sizes = "16x16" href = "images/logo16x16.png">
<link rel = "mask-icon" href = "images/logo.png">
<link rel = "shortcut icon" href = "images/logo.png">
```

**Correct path:**

Aside from the above, it seems that you also use an incorrect path to the favicon, which is why it doesn't work at all. Based on what you have said, your structure is the following:

```
/
- docs
   - index.html
- images
   - logo.png
```

With respect to the above structure, the correct relative path you have to use in your `html` file in order to get the favicon is `../images/logo.png`.

Answer (score 0):

if you add favicon your website.
favicon size 16x16 or 32x32 and then, this code block;

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

OR

https://www.favicon-generator.org/

Comment: can you share with me

Comment: I have added favicon in images folder and index.html is in docs folder and my docs and images folder are in my main folder what href="" should I use for my favicon ? <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"> but does not work can you tell me how to fix the path ?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/favicon.png"/>
```

Comment: I have decreased the size of my image now should I add above 2 lines in my html page ?

Comment: Yes you can use small icon image for that

Comment: What should be my `href="images/logo.png"` ?

Comment: Can you edit it with the required `href=""` as your code is not working ? where should I add my icon in file structure ?

Comment: your image is png or jpg

Comment: I have added favicon in main folder and my index.html file is in layout->partials->index.html what must be the path of my `href=""` ?

Comment: you use first link and ou just write `href="favicon.png"` your image name it will work not use second one

Comment: What must be the path given to display the image with title in `href=""` ?

Comment: href="favicon.png" will not work it because index.html file is in layout->partial-> index.html see the file structure in imgur url

Comment: `use href="./favicon.png"` or  `use href="./../favicon.png"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your image responsive. 300px image is big. You have to convert your images to different screen sizes in order to be responsive. So, use online tools to convert images to different screen sizes and normally range between 16 to 180.
When making a website, you need to consider about your resources to be hosted. For tab images, always keep images simply because you also need to consider your other resources as well